# c++ count down script

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int num, num2;
  num = 33;
  do
  {
      cout <<"\n" <<num-3;

}     
  while (num >=3);     
  system("PAUSE");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;  
}
```

I have coded the above but when I run it, it outputs 30 and does not deplete the value to 3. 
How can I have the loop do this? I know that num-- would work but that would only deplete the value by one. I'm new to c++ and I am trying to figure these things out.

Thanks! :)

//edit thanks I have it working now with num = num - 3, num-=3 works too

Comment: Use `num-=3` inside your loop

Comment: try `num = num-3` inside loop?

Comment: I dont know who down voted you, but I want to say thank you for taking the time to find a minimal example of your problem and posting code. So many people dont so this. And although the solution was relativley straightforward, you shouldnt get downvoted for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
cout <<"\n" <<num-3;
```

does not change the value of num. It just outputs the value of num - 3. To actually change the value you need another line, such as:

```
num -= 3;
```

Comment: You can technically do it in the output statement as well: `std::cout << (num -= 3);`

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do as suggested and subtract 3 (or whatever) every iteration of your loop, it may not do a whole lot of good. The problem is fairly simple: you're likely updating your variable a lot faster than the output can be printed, so you may easily see a dozen or more values all appear at essentially the same time.

To cure that, you generally want to pause for a short time between iterations, so one value will (probably) be visible before the next is printed. Based on the `system("pause");`, I'm going to guess you're running Windows, in which case code something like this may be a bit more to your liking:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num = 33;
    do
    {
        cout <<"    \r" << (num-=3);
        Sleep(100);
    }     
    while (num >=3);     
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;  
}
```